# Homeopathic remedy for low testosterone?

Tags: testosterone, erectile-dysfunction

When one has low testosterone, allopathy only has the Testosterone Replacement Therapy (TRT) available. This is a lifelong therapy and stops the natural production of testosterone.

Medicine for erectile dysfunction exists in homeopathy. Are there drugs in homeopathy to boost Testosterone, not replace it altogether?

Comment: Questions regarding personal recommendation are off-topic on Health for various reasons pointed out in the site's disclaimer. I have edited your question to make it on-topic. Please either accept, reject or rollback the edit. Furthermore, is your problem low testosterone or an erectile dysfunction ?

Comment: Typo is corrected. Both are my problems.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are not enough people familiar with evidence of homeopathy to adequately judge an answer to this question.  See previous homeopathy questions that have been downvoted or closed.

Answer (score 3):

I really recommend you go to a medical doctor for these issues.  I am all about evidence-based alternative medicine, but in general, Homeopathy has very poor evidence for being able to treat most things.  Another Meta-analysis this year of homeopathy have turned up empty on a lot of things.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeopathy#Systematic_reviews_and_meta-analyses_of_efficacy) referencing [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5366148/):

> A 2017 systematic review and meta-analysis found that the most
>   reliable evidence did not support the effectiveness of
>   non-individualized homeopathy. The authors noted that "the quality of
>   the body of evidence is low."

Its best efficacy is generally due to [placebo effect](https://www.health.harvard.edu/mental-health/the-power-of-the-placebo-effect), which may be responsible for its efficacy in ED, as many cases of ED have at least partial psychological etiology. Testosterone is part of your endocrine system, not as likely to respond to homeopathy.

Note that [erectile dysfunction in a young man can be herald of early cardiovascular disease](http://circ.ahajournals.org/content/123/21/e609).  More reason to get a doctor to see you.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5366148/

Comment: You may be right DoctorWhom . But I am looking for alternatives. I stopped smoking, PDE5 not working for me. Low testosterone. Maybe a PIED, I am on my rebooting period. Low libido. These are my problems.

Comment: You probably won't find an answer on homeopathy on this site, and we can't advise your individual situation.  Get a primary care provider who you can unite the big picture with -
 the recommendations of different doctors.  Specialists (urology) with endocrinology with psychiatry (if you're the guy who asked a similar question and is on the med that increases prolactin?) and get you connected with psychOLOGY/counseling.  Just because testosterone is low doesn't mean that is the only reason for ED.

Comment: Yes I am the guy. Thank you for the support. I am tested with MRI scan, and no problem in the result.